# Find the least distance between W and the vector v = (3 2 9).

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose, a space W is generated by the three column vectors a = (1 0 -1), b = (1 root(2) 1), c = (1 -root(2) 1). The question seems simple enough, but I don't know where to start. This is a practice question from my Linear Algebra undergrad course. Please help me out. Is it possible to solve this using orthogonal projections? If yes, then how do I find orthogonal basis for a set of vectors?

Comment: Vectors don't have location, so it's going to be pretty hard to find the distance from a vector to anything.

Comment: @B.Goddard OP mean column vector...

Comment: Here is a question for you: are those three column vectors linearly independent? If you don't see it by inspection, you can either compute the determinant of the matrix whose columns are those three vectors, or you can compute the [scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product). The vectors are linearly independent if and only if these are zero. (Once you've done that, let me know in a comment containing @TonyK, and I will be notified.)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here is a hint to get you started.

1. Find a (linearly independent) basis for $W$. How many vectors are there? (Should be 2 or 3 by inspection).
2. If 3, $\dim W = \dim \mathbb{R}^3$, what is the distance then?
3. If 2, $W$ is a plane. How do you find the minimum distance between a plane and a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Think about projecting the point onto the plane and finding the distance between the original point and its projection onto $W$.

Feel free to update your question with the results of your work, or ask below in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, so it is difficult to give an answer to your question. I will assume that the vector space is $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.

---

You have that $$W=\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\ -1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \sqrt{2}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -\sqrt{2}\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$$and $$v=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 2\\ 9\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{3}.$$
In your problem, you need calculate the least distance between subspace vector $W$ and $v$. Then, you need calculate $$d(v,M)=\operatorname{proj}_{W}(v):=\langle v, u_{1}\rangle u_{1}+\langle u,u_{2}\rangle u_{2}+\cdots \langle v,u_{n}\rangle u_{n}, $$where $\beta'_{W}=\{u_{1},u_{2},\ldots,u_{n}\}$ is a orthonormal basis to subspace vector $W$. Can you continue from here?